# Filtering a sorted column with SelectOneMenu in PrimeFaces DataTable

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I have the following column in a DataTable:

[image: Sorted column]

The problem is when I click the blue area, it first sorts the column and then opens the select options.

I tried adding `event.stopPropagation();return false` to the events `onclick`, `onkeyup` and `onkeydown` of my `p:selectOneMenu` but no success. I thought it was bubbling until the column and then sorting it but it seems that is not the case.

I think that is a bug, but I only have time to an workaround.

**So my question is:** Does anyone have experienced it and know how to fix it ?

Comment: I ran into the same problem (using PF community version 5.1). Have you found any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.1 seems to have fixed it.

There are many other bugs, but this one have been fixed.
Some known bugs and fixed by myself (I just overwrote the js code):

- Usage of pe:inputNumber (PrimeFaces Extension) in editable column
- Usage of TAB when only some(not all) columns are editable
- Context Menu on editable columns
- Usage of ESC to close dialogs created with Dialog Framework
- Prevent from auto focusing elements with refresh effect on blur